# Mi texto no se cambia de color teniendo dos clases asignadas

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estaba intentando hacer un cambiador de temas (claro - oscuro) y todo iba "bien" hasta que no se porqué me he topado con el error de que solo se cambian los textos que tienen una clase asignada, la que uso para cambiar el color (txt).

**JavaScript:**

```
document.querySelector(".txt").style.color = "black";
```

**HTML:**

```
<p id="txttema" class="txt">Cambiar al tema oscuro</p> <!-- Este si cambia -->
<p class="txt minititulo">Texto</p> <!-- Este no cambia -->
```

Os recalco, que lo que se me hace raro es que no funcione el que tiene dos clases y una sí (ya que supuestamente esas clases son independientes al menos que tengan alguna propiedad en común, que en este caso no la tienen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

> The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

si quieres mas de un elemento tienes que usar `querySelectorAll` aunque esto te retorna un array

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".txt").forEach(item => item.style.color = 'red');
```

```html
<p id="txttema" class="txt">Cambiar al tema oscuro</p> 
<p class="txt minititulo">Texto</p>
```

Comment: Perfecto. Muchísimas gracias, otra cosa que aprendo :).